# No output file created

Tags: python

Very simply, this code should be outputting a summary file, which it isn't, in a specified output directory. I can't figure out why

I have tried editing the configuration as well as changing directories.

```
import os
import pandas as pd


def summarise(indir, outfile):
os.chdir(indir)
filelist = ""
dflist = []
colnames = ["DSP Code", "Report Date", "Initial Date", "End Date", "Transaction Type", "Sale Type",
            "Distribution Channel", "Products Origin ID", "Product ID", "Artist", "Title", "Units Sold",
            "Retail Price", "Dealer Price", "Additional Revenue", "Warner Share", "Entity to be billed",
            "E retailer name", "E retailer Country", "End Consumer Country", "Price Code", "Currency Code"]
for filename in filelist:
    print(filename)
    df = pd.read_csv('SYB_M_20171001_20171031.txt', header=None, encoding='utf-8', sep='\t',
                     names=colnames, skiprows=1, usecols=['Units Sold', 'Dealer Price', 'End Consumer Country',
                                                          'Currency Code'])
    # Multiplying units by dealer price will give you sum of file
    df['Sum of Revenue'] = df['Units Sold'] * df['Dealer Price']
    # Get those first two columns
    d = {'Sum of Revenue': 'Total Revenue', 'Units Sold': 'Total Units'}
    for col, newcol in d.items():
        df.loc[df.index[0], newcol] = df[col].sum()
    # Add the rest for every country:
    s = df.groupby('End Consumer Country')['Units Sold'].sum().to_frame().T.add_suffix(' Total')
    s.index = [df.index[0]]

    df = pd.concat([df, s], 1, sort=False)
    df.to_csv(outfile + r"\output.csv", index=None)

    dflist.append(filename)


summarise(r"O:\James Upson\Sound Track Your Brand Testing\SYB Test",
      r"O:\James Upson\Sound Track Your Brand Testing\SYB Test Formatted")
```

I am expecting an output file called 'output.csv'

Comment: Are you sure your dataframe isn't empty before you try to write it? Why are you specifying `outfile` as an argument of your function if it's a folder. Also, why are you putting an r in front of your string? Could you try replace this line with `df.to_csv(outfile, index=None)` and calling your function with `summarise(indir, 'path/to/write/output.csv')` directly? (Also fix your indent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, ok, I see `filelist = ""` and then `for filename in filelist:`
Your trying to loop over an empty list

Comment: Any way around this. Unsure about what to remove/add. Help would be greatly appreciated :)